# GCP Cloud identity free still available?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

Trying to setup Google Cloud Identity free for testing organizational policies.
However I'm always redirected to Gsuite and can't seem to get Cloud Identity free enabled.
Is it still available or was it deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Identity has not been `deprecated`. Google Cloud Identity does not require G Suite, but if you do have G Suite then this service is integrated into your G Suite account.

If you are having a problem with redirection, open your browser using incognito mode.